# Trigger a "ENTER" in programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is possible to program a "Enter" after a value is added to a input text box?

If yes, I need help on my code below. It does't trigger the "ENTER" keypress.

My code as below:

```
$('#clo_cart').click( function () {

/*Save ENTER in variable*/
var eneterKey = jQuery.Event("keydown");
eneterKey.which = 13; 
eneterKey.keycode = 13;

$("#scan_char").focus().val('CLOSECTN').trigger(eneterKey);
}//end of button click
```

Pls Help

Comment: I think there are some differences between keydown and keypress in terms of the value assigned to `event.which`. Can you try with `keypress` event?

Comment: This seems a round-about way of doing things. Why not simply call whatever the 'enter' key would have triggered?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Can you me show some example?

Comment: @JSTai : what happen if you enter key ?

Comment: @NisargShah Thank bro. It Work!!!

Comment: @JSTai assume you have written a 10 lines of code that runs when you press the `Enter` key... what you can do is place this code in a function and then call this function when ever there is a `Enter` key press and also when ever you want to trigger the `Enter` key press.. hope this make sense

Comment: @user2486 After "Enter" trigger, my logic is to process or save data to DB. The concept is like "Checkout" after some add to cart.

Comment: This is guesswork. If it is a form, 'enter' would quite often trigger a form submission. So I would submit the from instead of emulating an 'enter' key stroke.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Agree. I post this question because my code didt work.

Comment: @JSTai : you just need to submit form , google for it not trigger enter.

Comment: @user2486 You are right too, however I would like the user to checkout via scanning a "CHECKOUT "barcode. Put it simple to kill 2 bird in 1 stone.

Comment: @JSTai : dont use stone , its 21st century, blast the world. `No code`, `No Question`.  you can add `form submit code by jquery` after `$("#scan_char").focus().val('CLOSECTN')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below work fine for me.

```
  $('#clo_cart').click( function () {

     $("#scan_char").focus().val('CLOSECTN').trigger(enterKey());

  }//end of button click

    /* Function to allow program keypress ENTER */
    function enterKey() {

       return $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `keydown` event with `keypress` event. There are some differences between how they use `event.which` property. This might be one of the cases where the two of them use different values for `event.which`.

```
var eneterKey = jQuery.Event("keypress");
```

Also note that `which` property has been deprecated. You can compare with the `event.key` property. It should have value `Enter` when the enter key is to be simulated.

```
$('#clo_cart').click( function () {

    /*Save ENTER in variable*/
    var eneterKey = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    eneterKey.key = 'Enter';

    $("#scan_char").focus().val('CLOSECTN').trigger(eneterKey);
}
```

Comment: @JSTai That's strange. I did verify that. Looks like it is not sending the value of `event.which` inside the event handler. So it might not be working because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
$('#clo_cart').click( function () {

var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
$("#scan_char").focus().val('CLOSECTN').trigger(e);

}//end of bu
```